# Where is hardware exception handling entry / exit code stored

Tags: exception, assembly, microcontroller, interrupt

I know this question seems very generic as it can depend on the platform,

but I understand with procedure / function calls, the assembler code to push return address on the stack and local variables etc. can be part of either the caller function or callee function.

When a hardware exception or interrupt occurs tho, the Program Counter will get the address of the exception handler via the exception table, but where is the actual code to store the state, return address etc. Or is this automatically done at the hardware level for interrupts and exceptions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some architectures don't save anything, some save the minimal context. When done by the SW, the code is part of the ISR. When done by the HW, it's either hardwired or microprogrammed.

Comment: But the return address at a very minimum must be saved? and status registers possibly?

Comment: This is too broad as it is architecture specific and you can simply look up the answer in the documentation you have or should have for this kind of development.  The minimum is a return address and some architectures have a hidden stack for that, some have alternate register banks.  And some architectures expand from that saving the status word (flags, etc) for you, or perhaps some registers for you as well as the pc and psr.  What architecture are you interested and what part of the manual did you not understand?

Comment: I would be interested in ARM for example. I am mainly wondering if the return address etc. is saved via software instructions the same as procedure calls or is it generally a special case with exceptions that stuff gets automatically saved via hardware

Comment: Yes, the return address must be saved. IIRC there exist architectures where the return address is saved in a specific register. But you got the idea, it is the HW the does what would be too late to be done by the SW :)

Comment: @Engineer999 then please edit your question (and the tags) and name the architecture. ARM alone is not enough, e.g. Cortex-M interrupt handling is quite different from Cortex-A.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For function calls, which occur at well defined (synchronous) locations in the program, the compiler generates executable instructions to manage the return address, registers and local variables.  These instructions are integrated with your function code.  The details are hardware and compiler specific.

For a hardware exception or interrupt, which can occur at any location (asynchronous) in the program, managing the return address and registers is all done in hardware.  The details are hardware specific.

Think about how a hardware exception/interrupt can occur at any point during the execution of a program.  And then consider that if a hardware exception/interrupt required special instructions integrated into the executable code then those special instructions would have to be repeated everywhere throughout the program.  That doesn't make sense.  Hardware exception/interrupt management is handled in hardware.

Comment: On some architectures, the hardware saves all registers. On others, it saves only the program counter and the processor flags. Others save a subset of the registers only, the subset can depend on the interrupt type.

Comment: Ok thanks. That pretty much completely answers my question :)

Answer (score 2):

since you are asking about arm and you tagged microcontroller you might be talking about the arm7tdmi but are probably talking about one of the cortex-ms.  these work differently than the full sized arm architecture.  as documented in the architectural reference manual that is associated with these cores (the armv6-m or armv7-m depending on the core) it documents that the hardware conforms to the ABI, plus stuff for an interrupt.  So the return address the psr and registers 0 through 4 plus some others are all put on the stack, which is unusual for an architecture to do.  R14 instead of getting the return address gets an invalid address of a specific pattern which is all part of the architecture, unlike other processor ip, addresses spaces on the cortex-ms are encouraged or dictated by arm, that is why you see ram starts at 0x20000000 usually on these and flash is less than that, there are some exceptions where they place ram in the "executable" range pretending to be harvard when really modified harvard.   This helps with the 0xFFFxxxxx link register return address, depending on the manual they either yada yada over the return address or they go into detail as to what the patterns you find mean.

likewise the address in the vector table is spelled out something like the first 16 are system/arm exceptions then interrupts follow after that where it can be up to 128 or 256 possible interrupts, but you have to look at the chip vendor (not arm) documentation for that to see how many they exposed and what is tied to what.  if you are not using those interrupts you dont have to leave a huge hole in your flash for vectors, just use that flash for your program (so long as you insure you are never going to fire that exception or interrupt).

Answer (score 0):

The "code" isn't software at all; by definition the CPU has to do it itself internally because interrupts happen asynchronously.  (Or for synchronous exceptions caused by instructions being executed, then the internal handling of that instruction is what effectively triggers it).

**So it's microcode or hardwired logic inside the CPU that generates the stores of a return address on an exception,** and does any other stuff that the architecture defines as happening as part of taking an exception / interrupt.

You might as well as where the code is that pushes a return address when the `call` instruction executes, on x86 for example where [the `call` instruction pushes return info onto the stack](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CALL.html) instead of overwriting a link register (the way most RISCs do).